# How to update environment variables in a StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I wants to update the environment variables in a Kubernetes StatefulSet. I Updated the YAML file and executed `$kubectl apply -f my-statefulset.yml`, but nothing changed. Then I tried `$kubectl scale sts my-statefulset --replicas=0; kubectl scale sts my-statefulset --replicas=4` and it only recreated the last pod in the StatefulSet.

Dropping my entire StatefulSet and recreating it just to change an environment variable does not looks like a good idea. `$kubectl patch` could work here, but I was not able to form the update json. I need a little help here on how to update environment variables in StatefulSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your StatefulSet name is `my-statefulset`, the below command should help you:

`kubectl patch statefulset my-statefulset -p '{"spec":{"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}}}'`

More information you can find in [Updating StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets) document.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I rather edited YAML file to have Rolling update:
spec:
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate